# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am experiencing an issue with this error, The code I have used is given below:

```
<?php
$cus_name = isset($_POST['client_name'])?$_POST['client_name']:'';
$description = isset($_POST['desc'])?$_POST['desc']:'';
$amount = isset($_POST['amnt'])?$_POST['amnt']:'';

$query = "INSERT INTO ".$RECORD_TABLE."(cus_name,description,amount) VALUES ('$cus_name','$description','$amount') " ;
$result = mysqli_query($dbObj,$query);

if(!$result)
{
  echo "error while inserting";
}


?>
```

That is the code I am using for insertion of date into the database. The connection code I am giving below:

```
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PWD = '';
$DB_NAME = 'hotel_booking';

$BOOKING_TABLE = 'hotel_booking';
$PRICING_TABLE = 'hotel_pricing';
$SETTING_TABLE = 'hotel_setting';
$RECORD_TABLE = 'hotel_record';
require_once('Database.class.php');

global $dbObj;
$dbObj = new Database($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_NAME,1,0);
```

Comment: I concur with the error message here, `Database !== mysqli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is for connection 
Try this code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_NAME);
```

and also change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$RECORD_TABLE."(cus_name,description,amount) VALUES ('".$cus_name."','".$description."','".$amount."') " ;
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Comment: The latter change is very optional.

Comment: it worked the form details is going into the db, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now your `$dbObj` is an object of `Database` class. If you waht to use with `mysqli_*`, then `$dbObj` should be like this.

```
$dbObj = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password","database name");
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) for more info.

Comment: It is not submitting at all now

Comment: Form is not submitting??

Comment: form was not submitting with the code you put up, but it's alright, i got the solution, Thanks Niranjan

Answer (score -2):

check whether class returns new mysqli

```
 class Database() {
    function __constructor(){
        $obj=mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PWD,$DB_NAME);
        return $obj;
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but shaymol bapary's answer worked